# how to restrict future month using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I'm using two dropdown(month, year). I've to restrict future month based on year. suppose if I choose '2014', it should show the months till January.I don't have any clue how to sort out this issue. please guide properly

```
<div class="width2 margin-bottom margin-top">
  <div class="profile-text">
    <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp;Certified On
   </div>
   <div class="profile-right">
     <s:select list="#{'':'---Select Month---','Jan':'Jan','Feb':'Feb',
        'Mar':'Mar','Apr':'Apr','May':'May','Jun':'Jun','July':'July',
        'Aug':'Aug','Sep':'Sep','Oct':'Oct','Nov':'Nov','Dec':'Dec'}" 
        name="month" id="month" data-toggle="tooltip" 
        title="Please enter the month" cssStyle="height:32px; width:49%;"
        placeholder="Month" cssClass="profile-input "/> 


      <s:select list="yearList" name="year" id="year" data-toggle="tooltip" 
        title="Please Enter Year" headerKey="" headerValue="--Select Year--" 
        cssStyle="height:32px; width:49%;" placeholder="Year" 
        cssClass="profile-input">      
      </s:select>        

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean it should show current month for running year and should show all months for past years ?

Comment: yes it should show current month for running year and should show all months for past years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
 $('#year').on('change',function() {
    var currMon= (new Date).getMonth();
    var currYear = (new Date).getFullYear();

    if(currYear === $('#year :selected').text()){
       $('#month option:eq('+currMon+')').prop('selected', true);
       $('#month').prop('disabled',true); 
    }  
    else{
       $('#month').prop('disabled',false); 
    }   
 });
```

*Note: the value of the month select should be `0` to `11`  representing jan to dec*

Happy Coding :)

Comment: ,Thanks for your answer.I've developed answer from your idea.

Answer (score 0):

$('#year').on('change',function() {

var option=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","June","July","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

var currMon= (new Date).getMonth();

var currYear = (new Date).getFullYear();

$('#month').html('');

if(currYear == $('#year :selected').text()&& currMon==0){

```
    for(i=0; i<=currMon; i++)
      {
        $('#month').append($("<option />").val(option[i]).text(option[i]));
      }
}else 
    {
    for(i=0; i<=11; i++)
  {
    $('#month').append($("<option />").val(option[i]).text(option[i]));
  }
    }
```

});